# How to dynamically change option display

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, select

I want users to submit their names, and the names will be on the option display.

HTML

```
<form action="#">
        <input type="text" id="p1Name">
        <input type="text" id="p2Name">
        <button id="start">Start</button>
</form>
<label for="selected">Select Player</label>
<select name="" id="selected">
            <option value="p1"><span id="select1">Player 1</span></option>// So "Player 1" and "Player 2" should be replaced by users's names 
            <option value="p2"><span id="select2">Player 2</span></option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
const p1 = {
    displaySelect: document.querySelector('#select1')
}
const p2 = {
    displaySelect: document.querySelector('#select1')
}


const startButton = document.querySelector('#start');
startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let nameOne = document.getElementById('p1Name').value;
    let nameTwo = document.getElementById('p2Name').value;
    p1.displaySelect.textContent = nameOne;
    p2.displaySelect.textContent = nameTwo;
})
```

It seems like **p1.displaySelect** is null. I've tried to look it up on the internet, but I can't really find one. Please take a look at my code.

```
app.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put your id inside the **option** tag. Instead, it should be within the **option** tag itself.

The method preventDefault within the code below helps to stop the HTML from redirecting you.

Hope this helps

```js
const p1 = {
    displaySelect: document.querySelector('#select1')
}
const p2 = {
    displaySelect: document.querySelector('#select2')
}


const startButton = document.querySelector('#start');
startButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let nameOne = document.getElementById('p1Name').value;
    let nameTwo = document.getElementById('p2Name').value;
    p1.displaySelect.textContent = nameOne;
    p2.displaySelect.textContent = nameTwo;
})
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" id="p1Name">
  <input type="text" id="p2Name">
  <button id="start">Start</button>
</form>
<label for="selected">Select Player</label>
<select name="" id="selected">
  <option value="p1" id="select1"><span>Player 1</span></option>// So "Player 1" and "Player 2" should be replaced by users's names
  <option value="p2" id="select2"><span>Player 2</span></option>
</select>
```